# R: Scoping, timing, and <<-

Tags: r, scope, promise, arguments, lazy-evaluation

In the code below, I expect both f and the final a to return 3. But in fact they both return 2. Why is this? Hasn't 3 replaced 2 in the enclosing environment at the time the promise is evaluated?

```
a <- 1

f <- function(a){
  a <<- 3
  cat(a)
}

f(a <- 2)
a
```

Note that If I use an = instead of a <- in the call to f, the final a is 3 as expected, but f remains 2.

Comment: This is one of the cases where there is a differnce between `=` and `<-`. If used the `=` is used in the function call, it's treated as a named parameter. If you just use `a<-2` then it's an unnamed parameter that's not evaluated till you run `cat(a)` which evaluates in the calling environment, overwritting the global assignment before it. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: To expand on @MrFlick's comment: if you run `get("a",envir = .GlobalEnv)` at each step on debugging `f` you'll see it returns values of 1, then 3, and at that point you're just about to evaluate `cat(a)`. Evaluating that finds the _argument_ first, not the `a` in the global environment, so it evaluates `a <- 2` in the calling environment, hence overwriting it again to 2.

Comment: Thanks, Joran, that's helpful. So what I was missing was that the assignment to a in the command line does not take place until the promise of a is fulfilled. I thought that was only for assignments with =.  I mean <- is not peculiar to function definition. It is a full-fledged closure in its own right, and this implies that closures get special evaluation rules when they are function arguments. I find it frustrating that I have never found a good definition of when a variable is "used" in the sense of triggering promise fulfillment.

Comment: MrFlick, I am trying to overcome my all-to-frequent failure to predict correctly what R code that I write will do. My current strategy for that is to break the process of function evaluation down into the finest possible steps (I'm up to 15 and don't think I have them all yet) and then make sure that I really understand each step. In the process of doing that I raise a lot of questions about the exact mechanism of the step, try to test hypotheses for the mechanism, and pin down the areas I still do not understand. But I still run into results I do not expect or understand occasionally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through the code

```
a <- 1
```

assigns the value 1 to the name `a` in the global environment.

```
f <- function(a){...}
```

creates a function saved to the name `f` in the global environment.

```
f(a <- 2)
```

Now we are calling the function `f` with the expression  `a<-2` as a parameter. This expression is not evaluated immediately. It is passed as a promise. The global value of `a` remains 1.

Now we enter the body of the function `f`. The expression we've passed in is assigned to the local variable `a` in the function scope (still un-evaluated) and `a` in the global remains 1. The fact they they both involve the symbol `a` is irrelevant. There is no direct connection between the two `a` variables here.

```
a <<- 3
```

This assigns the value of 3 to a in a parent scope via `<<-` rather than the local scope as `<-` would do. This means that the `a` refered to here is not the local `a` that now hold the parameter passed to the function. So this changes the value of `a` in the global scope to 3. And finally

```
cat(a)
```

Now we are finally using the value that was passed to the function since the `a` here refers to the `a` in the local function scope. This triggers the promise `a <- 2` to be run in the calling scope (which happens to be the global scope). Thus the global value of `a` is set to 2. This assignment expression returns the right-hand-side value so "2" is displayed from `cat()`.

The function exits and

```
a
```

shows the value of the `a` in the global environment which is now `a`. It was only the value 3 in the brief moment between the two expressions in `f`.

If you where to call

```
f( a=2 )
```

This is very different. Now we are not passing an expression to the function anymore, we are passing the value 2 to the named function parameter `a`. If you tried `f(x=2)` you would get an error that the function doesn't recognize the parameter named "x". There is no fancy lazy expression/promise evaluation in this scenario since 2 is a constant. This would leave the global value set to 3 after the function call. `f(a <- 2)` and `f(a = a <- 2)` would behave the same way.

Comment: This is a terrific explanation. I had wrapped my mind around a comment in another stackoverflow post, that <- did assignment in the calling environment, not in the execution environment. Your very clear step-by-step shows that it actually does both – but at different times.